# Do the playstore updates work if the app is installed with apk?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Do the updates work if the app is installed with an apk (Sideloading)?

I would like to deliver the Android devices with my pre-installed app and the devices will receive updates later if the customer logs on with his own account.

Answer (score 1):

Play Store updates work only if the app is already in the user's library i.e. the user has installed the app once via Play Store and the update signature is the same. Otherwise, Play Store updates will not work.